# Tool for linking Images (jpg) to HTML pages automatically

Tags: html, image, automation

I have thousands of HTML pages, I need to take a screenshot (make a thumbnail of it) of each page and the link the image(thumbnail to the HTML file) formed by the screenshot (thumbnail) to the respective HTML page.

Looking for a tool which would automate this process, Manually linking so many pages would take lot of time.

Comment: Why would you need to link a screenshot of a html page to itself?

Comment: I want to make thumbnails of the HTML and link it to actual HTML upon clicking the thumbnail

Answer (score -1):

You can use wink software to capture desktop. Wink will generate images. That images you can use for linking in html.
Once images are generated you can write a program that will link image of each page into it.

Comment: Well, the main problem is connecting the thumbnail (image) to the HTML. can you guide me writing such a code to connect the thumbnail to the HTML page?

Thanks.